# Amazon SES - Is there a build in Opt-out / Unsubscribe option is available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is there a build in Opt-out / Unsubscribe option is available for SES?

Like we can include a header in the mail so that an unsubscribe button appears in the mail?

Comment: @john you might want to take a look at: https://github.com/MoonMail/MoonMail

Comment: I think this is something different. My requirement is to send unsubscribe link option along with a reminder mail sent from our system scheduler.

Answer (score 11):

It seems like now they support unsubscribe option, from their docs:

> Amazon SES provides a subscription management capability, in which
> Amazon SES automatically enables the unsubscribe links in every
> outgoing email when you specify the contactListName and topicName
> within ListManagementOptions in the SendEmail operation request.

Further down in their docs, they also mention:

> You will need to use the {{amazonSESUnsubscribeUrl}} placeholder in
> templated and non-templated emails to specify where Amazon SES needs
> to insert the unsubscribe URL.

For more details see their docs: [Using Subscription Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-subscription-management.html)

Answer (score 5):

No. Amazon SES doesn't have built in opt - out/ unsubscribe option for email.

From their documentation:

> When you use Amazon SES to receive mail, you can develop software
>   solutions such as email autoresponders, email unsubscribe systems, and
>   applications that generate customer support tickets from incoming
>   emails [SES Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html)